# Default font size on the status bar

Tags: macos, font, ios

What is the default font and **size** of the font on the status bar on El Capitan and Sierra?

My guess is: San Francisco size 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess at 11pt, SanFransisco.

Standard list views are 12pt, the headers are smaller, but not small enough to be 10.

You can test by eye...

Open any finder window
Hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd> 
Change the text size until it appears to match the status bar.
Zooming the screen might help comparison [ <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  + scroll wheel by default]

This is a quick attempt at matching, artificially zoomed in Photoshop...

[image]